# How can I make my form submit button open a different URL based on radio button selection using JavaScript function?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, submit

I'm new at JavaScript so sorry if this really simple...

What I am trying to accomplish:

Have a form with 10 different radio button selections.
On the Submit button click, the user should be redirected to a new URL based on their selection.

Here is my HTML Form:

```
<form onsubmit="myFunction()" class="final_question">
    <div class="question-container">
        <div class="form-box first-answer">
        <label for="Option1">Option 1</label>
        <input type="radio" id="Option1" name="option">
        </div>

        <div class="form-box second-answer">
        <label for="Option2">Option 2</label>
        <input type="radio" id="Option2" name="option">
        </div>

        <div class="form-box third-answer">
        <label for="Option3">Option 3</label>
        <input type="radio" id="Option3" name="option">
        </div>

        <div class="form-box fourth-answer">
        <label for="Option4">Option 4</label>
        <input type="radio" id="Option4" name="option">
        </div>

        <div class="form-box fifth-answer">
        <label for="Option5">Option 5</label>
        <input type="radio" id="Option5" name="option">
        </div>

        <div class="form-box sixth-answer">
        <label for="Option6">Option 6</label>
        <input type="radio" id="Option6" name="option">
        </div>

        <div class="form-box seventh-answer">
        <label for="Option7">Option 7</label>
        <input type="radio" id="Option7" name="option">
        </div>

        <div class="form-box eighth-answer">
        <label for="Option8">Option 8</label>
        <input type="radio" id="Option8" name="option">
        </div>

        <div class="form-box ninth-answer">
        <label for="Option9">Option 9</label>
        <input type="radio" id="Option9" name="option">
        </div>

        <div class="form-box tenth-answer">
        <label for="Option10">Option 10</label>
        <input type="radio" id="Option10" name="option">
        </div>
        
        <div class="form-box submit-button">
        <input type="submit" class="final_question_submit" id="mysubmit">
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Here is my JavaScript function (with dummy URLs inserted):

```
function myFunction() {
    if(document.getElementById('Option1').checked) {
        document.getElementById('mysubmit').href = "https://www.google.com";
    }
    else if(document.getElementById('Option2').checked) {
        document.getElementById('mysubmit').href = "https://facebook.com";
    }
    else if(document.getElementById('Option3').checked) {
        document.getElementById('mysubmit').href = "https://www.instagram.com";
    }
    else if(document.getElementById('Option4').checked) {
        document.getElementById('mysubmit').href = "https://www.twitter.com";
    }
    else if(document.getElementById('Option5').checked) {
        document.getElementById('mysubmit').href = "https://www.stackoverflow.com";
    }
    else if(document.getElementById('Option6').checked) {
        document.getElementById('mysubmit').href = "https://www.w3cschools.com";
    }
    else if(document.getElementById('Option7').checked) {
        document.getElementById('mysubmit').href = "https://www.freecodecamp.org";
    }
    else if(document.getElementById('Option8').checked) {
        document.getElementById('mysubmit').href = "https://www.edabit.com";
    }
    else if(document.getElementById('Option9').checked) {
        document.getElementById('mysubmit').href = "https://www.scrimba.com";
    }
    else(document.getElementById('Option10').checked) {
        document.getElementById('mysubmit').href = "https://www.javascript.com";
    }
}
```

Comment: May I ask why you use a `<form>`... when you actually don't need it? Or you do need? or wait, no, you want to go to another page.... hmm

Comment: Are you facing any kind of error?

Comment: Hmmm...Didn't think of not using a form...you mean replace the submit button with an anchor tag? I'll try.

Comment: No error specifically...all that happens when I make a selection and click submit is that the page refreshes instead of going to the link specified in my function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forms works with elements names

```js
const 
  direction = 
    {
    Option1: 'https://www.google.com"',
    Option2: 'https://facebook.com',
    Option3: 'https://www.instagram.com',
    Option4: 'https://www.twitter.com',
    Option5: 'https://www.stackoverflow.com',
    Option6: 'https://www.w3cschools.com',
    Option7: 'https://www.freecodecamp.org',
    Option8: 'https://www.edabit.com',
    Option9: 'https://www.scrimba.com"',
    Option10: 'https://www.javascript.com'
    }
, myForm = document.getElementById('my-form')
  ;
myForm.onsubmit=e=>
  {
  e.preventDefault()
  if (myForm.option.value) 
     document.location = direction[ myForm.option.value  ]
  }
```

```css
label, button {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  clear: both;
  width: 7em;
  margin: .5em;
  }
input[type=radio] {
  float: right;
  }
```

```html
<form action="" id="my-form">
  <label> Option 1  <input type="radio" name="option" value="Option1" > </label>
  <label> Option 2  <input type="radio" name="option" value="Option2" > </label>
  <label> Option 3  <input type="radio" name="option" value="Option3" > </label>
  <label> Option 4  <input type="radio" name="option" value="Option4" > </label>
  <label> Option 5  <input type="radio" name="option" value="Option5" > </label>
  <label> Option 6  <input type="radio" name="option" value="Option6" > </label>
  <label> Option 7  <input type="radio" name="option" value="Option7" > </label>
  <label> Option 8  <input type="radio" name="option" value="Option8" > </label>
  <label> Option 9  <input type="radio" name="option" value="Option9" > </label>
  <label> Option 10 <input type="radio" name="option" value="Option10"> </label>
  <button type="submit">submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks Mister Jojo....this one worked very well. Just have to re-style the css....I also think I'm having issues because the client is using Wordpress.com and there are a lot of limitations for adding JS in Wordpress it seems.

Comment: @ChristopherDennis  sorry, i don't know anything about wordPress, but i would be surprised if you couldn't embed such simple code in it?

Answer (score 0):

- Use `value=""` Option attribute
- Stop using inline `on*=""` attributes, the same way you (hopefully) don't use inline `style=""` attributes. its hard to debug, JS should go in one place only, and that's your Script tag or file.
- Take a look at [Document location](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/location)
- Take a look at Event.preventDefault()
- Don't use `for=""` when not needed.
- Use the `:checked` pseudo selector in JS's [`.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)

```js
const EL_finalForm = document.querySelector("#final_question");

EL_finalForm.addEventListener("submit", (ev) => {
  ev.preventDefault();
  const EL_checked = EL_finalForm.querySelector('input[name="option"]:checked');
  if (!EL_checked) return alert("Select an option");
  document.location = EL_checked.value;
});
```

```html
<form id="final_question">
  <div class="question-container">
    <label class="form-box">
        <span>Option 1</span>
        <input type="radio" value="https://www.google.com" name="option">
    </label>
    <label class="form-box">
        <span>Option 2</span>
        <input type="radio" value="https://www.facebook.com" name="option">
    </label>
    <label class="form-box">
        <span>Option 3</span>
        <input type="radio" value="https://www.instagram.com" name="option">
    </label>
    <label class="form-box">
      <input type="submit" class="final_question_submit">
    </label>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
window.open("https://your.url")
```

Instead of using:

```
document.getElementById('mysubmit').href = "https://www.javascript.com";
```

And if you want to open the window in the same tab:

```
window.open("https://www.youraddress.com","_self")
```